# Serializing bison recursive rule to a comma separated string or a vector

Tags: parsing, bison

I have the following grammar:

```
program
    :
    | program stm 
    ;

stm 
    : stmt 
    | expr
    ;

stmt 
    : import_stmt 
    ;

expr
    : value
    ;

value
    : STRING | DECIMAL | FLOAT | ID 
    ;

import_stmt
    : KW_IMPORT import_ids END {
        std::cout << "importing " << $2 << "\n"; 
      } 
    ;

import_ids
    : ID
    | import_ids "," ID
    ;
```

The goal I want to achieve, is that I want the value of `import_ids` be a comma separated string. So if I'll parse the following code: `import a, b, c, d;`, the value of an `$2` placeholder in the `import_stmt` rule will either be a comma separated string `a, b, c, d`, or vector with these letters as its members.

Actually I have not tried anything since I don't know how to do this, tried googling but no result.

Comment: You need to know how to make semantic actions produce values that will appear in the places of non-terminals during rule reduction. Look into `%union` and `%type` directives in bison. I'm unsure of the C++ way of doing this, since many types you'd wish to slot into a union aren't plain old data objects. Anyway, these parsers work bottom-up which makes it easy to, say, build lists by "cons"ing onto the front of a list already on the parsing stack from a previous reduction. Can also probably do something to work with vectors or strings if you wish. The core idea is having the parser build data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use semantic values in the actions (the `$2` you have), you need to tell bison about the types you want to use and consistently set the computed value in every action.

If you're using a C++-based parser, this is reasonably straight-forward -- you need to set the type of the value associated each terminal and non-terminal.  So something like:

```
%language "C++"
%define api.value.type variant

%token<std::string> ID         // IDs have a string associated with them
%type<std::string> import_ids  // as does this non-terminal
// ... %type for other non-terminals and %token for other token types

%%

// ... various rules

import_ids
    : ID  { $$ = $1 }
    | import_ids ',' ID { $$ = $1 + ", " + $3; }
    ;
```

This uses `std::string`'s built-in concatenation (operator+) to concatenate the strings.  However, it also requires using bison's C++ interface which greatly complicates your lexer.

If you're *not* using a C++ based parser (Using a C parser with the traditional yacc `%union` or with `api.type.variant union`), then you can't use complex C++ types in the union as they won't get constructed and destroyed properly.  If you want to use strings in that case, you'll need to worry about memory management for them, allocating and freeing them appropriately to avoid leaks.